# Is there a topology such that

Tags: general-topology

> Is there a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $[a,b]$ is not compact?

I thought to the discrete topology. Let $\mathcal{U}={U_i}$ a open cover of $[a,b]$. Since I have the discrete topology, $\forall x \in [a,b],$ {$x$} $\in \tau$. So $U_i=${$x$}. But then I can't take a finite sub cover because I wouldn't take an infinite number of {$x_i$} that wouldn't be cover.

It' ok?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Ok, thanks !    @bof

Comment: The Sorgenfrey line (a.k.a. the lower-limit topology, a.k.a. the right-half open topology) is another example. In the Sorgerfrey line an open set is the union of sets of the form $[a,b).$  So if $a< b$ then $\{\;[a, b-2^{-n}(b-a)): n\in \mathbb N\} \cup \{\;[b,b+1)\}$ is an open cover of $[a,b]$ with no finite sub-cover.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet As you might know, in the Sorgenfrey line, all compact sets are at most countable.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma. I hadn't known that, but it's fairly obvious (to me) now that you've mentioned it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is right, but it’s not well-written:

“*Let $\mathcal U = U_i…$ be a open cover. … So $U_i = \{x\}$. …*” suggests that *every* open cover of $[a..b]$ consists of only singeltons (which is false). Apart from that, you rather mean “*$\mathcal U = \{U_i;~i ∈ I\}$ for some index set $I$*”. Else, if you literally mean $\mathcal U = U_i$ – which “$i$” and why do you need two names for the same thing?

Instead write “*Let $\mathcal U = \{ \{x\};~x ∈ [a..b]\}$. Then $\mathcal U$ is an open cover of $[a..b]$, but …*”.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I knew it was a really simple question and I also know that I wasn't formal at all... but thanks so much, your answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Your example basically works, but you should give a specific open cover for which there is no finite subcover.  [Some open covers could have a finite subcover.]  One that would work would be $\{\{x\}_{x\in [a,b]}\}$; that is the collection of singleton sets.

Comment: thanks @paw88789 , exactly what I meant (but written much better ;) )

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help.